# How can I have TapGestureRecognizer + didSelectItemAt without them blocking each other?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have this gestureRecognizer that let me close the keyboard on tap anywhere in the screen. The problem is that when I try to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegate`, the `didSelectItemAt` gets blocked by the gesture recognizer, and I need to `double tap` for it to work properly.

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
```

Is there any way I can have both at the same time without them blocking each other?

Comment: Why don't you enable the tap only while the keyboard is present?

Comment: Oh, great idea, let me try to implement it. and i tell you

Comment: Okay, thank you. It was really easy. I think this quarantine is hurting me